# Python Regex Word Boundaries not working as expected

Tags: python, regex

Why isn't the word boundary working?

reading [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), I know a word boundary works like this:

There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:

- Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
- After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
- Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

The `a` string below appears to fit at least one of the positions listed above.

```
a = 'Builders Club The Ohio State'
re.sub('\bThe\b', '', a, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

output. There is no change in the 'The'.

```
'Builders Club The Ohio State'
```

Why isn't the word boundary working?

When I put spaces before and after ' The ' pattern, the regex appears to work.

```
a = 'Builders Club The Ohio State'
re.sub(' The ', ' ', a, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

output:

```
'Builders Club Ohio State'
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to use a [raw-string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) for your Regex pattern (which does not process escape sequences):

```
>>> import re
>>> a = 'Builders Club The Ohio State'
>>> re.sub(r'\bThe\b', '', a, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
'Builders Club  Ohio State'
>>>
```

Otherwise, `\b` will be interpreted as a backspace character:

```
>>> print('x\by')
y
>>> print(r'x\by')
x\by
>>>
```

Comment: To elaborate: The backslash is an escape character in normal strings and thus `\b` becomes just [a backspace character](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html). So either you need to use `\\b` or a raw string literal.

Comment: Generally whenever using regex it's a good idea to use a raw string.

Comment: ah ic. if I use r" will it mess up other characters, like ^ and $?

Comment: @user3314418 No, it only affects the number of backslashes you need to use (Hint: you don't need as many with a raw string)

Comment: I got the point. I tried the regex `r'\b\[details\]\b'` to remove **[details]** in my text. But word boundary didn't work. It worked without `\b` since I don't have any text that contains **[details]** as a substring. Even though I have a solution for the data that I have I feel like it is not generalized. Any suggestions about what is going on in my code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'\bThe\b', re.IGNORECASE)
test_str = u"Builders Club The Ohio State"
subst = u""

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

output:

```
Builders Club Ohio State
```

Here is [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cJ3kS9/1)